# D3:Word Cloud (Orientation and Rotation)

Tags: d3.js, word-cloud

I have downloaded the files for [Word cloud visualization](https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/) from GitHub, but I am cannot see how they are taking `Orientation` and `Rotation` values to change the word cloud.

Where is the code they have written to use orientation and rotation?

I can use `.rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 6- 2.5) * 30; })` to have a random rotated words but I want to implement the same as jasondavies has done.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be happening in

```
function cloudSprite(contextAndRatio, d, data, di) {
```

around line 245-285

what happens is he is using a spiral, it attempts to place it somewhere on the spiral, using the angle and distance of the spiral itself, and keeps on trying until it fits. Really neat stuff!

You can see how the algorithm works visually at http://static.mrfeinberg.com/bv_ch03.pdf page 52.